# running hive script in a shell script via oozie shell action

Tags: shell, hive, oozie

I have shell script " test.sh " as below

```
#!/bin/bash
export UDR_START_DT=default.test_tab_$(date +"%Y%m%d" -d "yesterday")
echo "Start date : "$UDR_START_DT
hive -f tst_tab.hql
```

the above shell script is saved in a folder in hadoop

```
/scripts/Linux/test.sh
```

the tst_tab.hql contains a simple create table statement, as I am just testing to get the hive working. This hive file is saved in the My documents folder in hue (same folder where my workflow is saved)

I have created an Oozie workflow that calls test.sh in a shell action.

Issue I am facing:

the above shell script runs successfully until line 3.
but when I add line 4 (hive -f tst_tab.hql), it generates the error

> Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain], exit code [1]

I verified YARN logs too. Nothing helpful there.

Comment: You do not pass the variable $UDR_START_DT to the Hive script. Use -hiveconf option. I don't know is it an issue, you didn't provide the script itself

Comment: Try to find YARN logs. There should be more informative exception log

Comment: Do you have a good reason _not_ to use the standard Hive action in your Oozie workflow?

Comment: Thank you leftjoin.  since I am just testing, I am not yet passing any variable to the tst_tab.hql . it just contains a simple create statement.  my problem here is that the hive query is not running when called from the .sh script. can it be due some env settings ?

Comment: Dear Samson, my goal is create tables dynamically based on variables extracted from current date. I am unable to concatenate variables and then use it to create a table in Hive. hence trying to do the same via a ,sh file.

Comment: _"unable to concatenate variables"_ > Oozie supports a subset of JSP "Expression Language" (EL) so you can _(a)_ extract the execution date from Coordinator in a custom format, _(b)_ pass that date to the Workflow, _(c)_ concatenate with whatever Worflow variables you have and pass the result as a Hive parameter.